# MainActivity.kt don't recognizing "ID's" in activity_main.xml

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a problem that i can't solve.
When i'm writing an ID in MainActivity then it's showing like it doesn't exist but it's in activity_main.

Please help - restart, "Sync project with Gradle files" and Clean Project don't help

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvExpression"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80sp"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/numberButton"
        android:textSize="40sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt :

```
package com.example.procalculator

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        tvExpression

    }
}
```

Comment: use findViewByID if you are not using Kotlin synthetic

Comment: @BurhanKhanzada OP is _trying_ to use synthetic imports, but they're just deprecated. you can see the answer i've provided for more info :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `findViewById` for the activity to find the view.

```
val tvExpression = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvExpression)
```

Personally I really recommend ViewBinding:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding
it saves a lot of unnecessary code

Gradle:

```
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)
binding.tvExpression //it's refereing to your textView
```

Comment: How to do it without adding anything like here ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpP6KgJtHTk&t=108s    time : 8:10

Comment: bro in the video that you are referring to is using kotlin synthetic and now its deprecated so just simply use findViewByID or viewBinding

Comment: for synthetics to work you need to add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` to Gradle